# Why Texstudio somtimes autocomplete the longer command?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I wanted to input the command `\rightarrow` in Texstudio, so I just typed `\righta` and then Textstudio gave me two suggestions `\rightarrow` and `\rightarrowtail`.

[image]

As the command `\rightarrow` was selected, I thought Texstudio should complete what is selected. However, I pressed the key Tab on my keyboard, only to find `\rightarrowtail` was completed by Texstudio.

[image]

This didn't occur once. So why Texstudio somtimes autocomplete the longer command? I canceled all extra options autocomplete in settings, but it's still useless.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using TexStudio for about ten years now. And although I have to scratch behind my ears at times when I get an unexpected result, it's usually my own fault giving me an `aha` moment of reflection.

In your case pressing `Tab` actually selects the next command in line and after pressing `Tab` twice that command is selected (the second time `Tab` is followed by `Enter`).

You can use the `up` and `down` arrows to select the desired command followed by either a mouse click or `Enter`. Just don't use `Tab` .

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really don't know that I should use Enter to autocomplete. I get accustomed on Tab lol.